# Copying rows from another sheet based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a tracker form of some sort that when the fields in the Form are populated, it get sent to the Consolidated sheet, but I need to get them to be sent to another sheet based on criteria (Column P). The below is the current code.

```
Sub Transfer()
    Set FormSht = Sheets("Tracker Form")
    Set MasterSht = Sheets("Consolidated")

    LR_form = FormSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NR_master = MasterSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For RowX = 1 To LR_form
        ColX = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FormSht.Cells(RowX, "A"), MasterSht.Rows(1), 0)
        MasterSht.Cells(NR_master, ColX) = FormSht.Cells(RowX, "B")
    Next RowX
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Sub Transfer(sheet_name As String)

    Set FormSht = Sheets("Tracker Form")
    Set MasterSht = Sheets(sheet_name)

    LR_form = FormSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NR_master = MasterSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For RowX = 1 To LR_form
        ColX = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FormSht.Cells(RowX, "A"), MasterSht.Rows(1), 0)
        MasterSht.Cells(NR_master, ColX) = FormSht.Cells(RowX, "B")
    Next RowX
End Sub

Sub cool_criteria()

'use your filter criterias here, if you have multiple try googeling "vba Select...Case"
If 2 > 1 Then
    sheet_name = "Consolidated"
Else
    sheet_name = "another sheet"
End If

Call Transfer(sheet_name)

End Sub
```

use the cool_criteria macro to set the filters which will then call the transfer macro.

Comment: I don't think so:

Basically what it should do is:

After the macro was run (what I provided), I'd make another macro to copy paste the data from the Consolidated tab, but filtered from Column P (Business Area), and copy paste them to the destination sheet (i.e. on Consolidated tab, filtered to "Consumer Banking" and all data from A:AC (excluding Headers) is copied to tab "Consumer Banking) (its fine if all are copied as long as they overwrite the current data in the sheets)